# Does distinct subformulas in this context mean syntactically distinct or semantically different?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

In Freindly introduction to mathematical logic, there is a procedure to convert the first order logic formulas into propositional formulas, this is a natural way to convert FOL's formulas into propositional formulas, here is the procedure:

[image]

My question is, If I have the first order logic formula $(=x_1x_2) \rightarrow (=x_2x_1)$ and I want to convert it into a propositional formula using the above procedure, Should I get 
$A\rightarrow A$ or $A\rightarrow B$? ($A$ and $B$ are two propositional variables)

In other words, Are the two formulas $(=x_1x_2)$ and $(=x_2x_1)$ distinct?

I don't know whether I should deal with them syntactically and so they will be distinct or semantically and so they are the same (not different).

So, What is the right thing?

Comment: Nice question. By the way, what are $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @goblin, they are propositional variables. I will add this to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are distinct.

Thus, if $\beta$ is $(=x_1,x_2) → (=x_2,x_1)$, then $\beta_P$ must be : $A \rightarrow B$ (with $A,B$ sentential letters).

The transormation is a "syntactical" one; thus you are considering a formula of the "logical form" :

> $R(x_1,x_2) \rightarrow R(x_2,x_1)$

and you do not know that $R$ is symmetric.

---

The issue is that every *instance* of a (propositional) *tautology* is a valid formula, but not vice versa.

From the tautology $A \lor \lnot A$ you can derive the valid instance $(x=y) \lor \lnot (x=y)$ but the "propositional transformation" of the valid $x=x$ is simply $A$, which of course is not a tautology.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much :)